# Using Socket and Threads Why Is my Chat Server so Slow and CPU Usage so High?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, chat, latency, ruby-1.9.3

So my code works fine except for when iterating through arrays and sending a response to multiple chat clients the latency between each client's reception of the response is nearly a second. I'm running the server and client on my computer so there shouldn't be any real latency, right? I know ruby isn't this slow. Also, why does my computer's fan spin up when running this? There's a bit more if it would be helpful to include it.

```
# Creates a thread per client that listens for any messages and relays them to the server viewer and all the other clients.
create_client_listener_threads = Thread.new do
    x = nil
    client_quantity = 0
    # Loops indefinitely
    until x != nil
        #Checks to see if clients have joined since last check.
        if @client_join_order_array.size > client_quantity
            # Derives number of new arrivals.
            number_of_new_arrivals = @client_join_order_array.size - client_quantity
            # Updates number of clients in client_quantity.
            client_quantity = @client_join_order_array.size
            if number_of_new_arrivals != 0
                # Passes new arrivals into client for their thread creation.
                @client_join_order_array[-1 * number_of_new_arrivals..-1].each do |client|
                    # Creates thread to handle receiving of each client's text.
                    client_thread = Thread.new do
                        loop do
                            text = client.acception.gets
                            # Displays text for server viewer.
                            puts "#{client.handle} @ #{Time.now} said: #{text}"
                            @client_hash.each_value do |value|
                                if value.handle != client.handle
                                    # Displays text for everyone except server viewr and person who spoke.
                                    value.acception.puts "#{client.handle} @ #{Time.now} said: #{text}"
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It looks like your loop is spinning without waiting. That's going to make the CPU hot...

Comment: Yeah. Adding a sleep(1) to the main thread fixed all of my problems. I'm still confused because I have other threads spinning constantly that do more than compare a number to another number every time they run, but they aren't causing high CPU usage or latency.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. It looks like my other threads do more, but they actually all wait for input from the client, or from the server user. I think they cause what's called a Global Interpreter Lock. I assumed that while waiting for input, (from clients at least) they would have to be doing something over and over. But that is obviously not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing `if @client_join_order_array.size > client_quantity`, and doing nothing except smoke the CPU if it is false, you should be *accepting the new connection* at this point, and blocking until there is one. In other words move the code that accepts connections and adds them to the array here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Adding sleep() did stop the CPU smoking, but your idea consolidates my code and made me realize that I don't need  separate threads for connecting to clients and adding threads that read and redistribute their messages. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need anything, let alone a thread, for connecting to clients. The clients connect to you. All you need is an accept loop, and a thread per client to handle its I/O.